# excel into matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, loops, import

I have several excel spreadsheets in a folder, where each spreadsheet contains several worksheets. I've written a code which loads a specific worksheet from each spreadsheet into matlab. The worksheet is called 'Bass min'.

```
files = dir('*.xls');
    %read data from excel into matlab
for i=1:length(files);
    File_Name{i}=files(i,1).name;%Removes the file names from 'files'
    [num{i},txt{i},raw{i}] = xlsread(File_Name{i},'Bass min');
end
```

Is there a faster way of doing this? As I have many spreadsheets its takes a long time to read. I've heard some people mentioning actxserver as a faster method, but don't know how this would work!

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reading the files in basic mode, in which case Matlab would read the files directly without going through Excel:

```
[num{i},txt{i},raw{i}] = xlsread(File_Name{i},'Bass min','','basic');
```

Comment: Warning: XLSREAD has limited import functionality on in basic mode.